# JQuery selector problem in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have a jquery selector that looks like:

```
alert($("#editform #action").val());
```

input box(id=action) is inside form ( id = editform), I am trying to alert value of inputbox action.

This works just fine in Firefox, Chrome but not in IE 6 or IE7.  the alert value is "undefined"

anyone knows how to sort it out?

Comment: Hi @Ej Huang what happens if you just use the selector "#action", without "#editform"? Could you post a snippet of your HTML as well please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need an element id.

```
alert($("#action").val());
```

Comment: Adeel, there are some elements which id is action on page. but they are in the different containers. so I want to get value of action in specific container editform.